# Is it possible to configure retries with the AWS CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I have a script which uses the AWS CLI (currently v1.11.90) to coordinate various AWS resources. Amongst other things it calls `aws cloudformation list-stacks` three or four times in a row.

I fairly frequently get errors because my requests are being throttled:

```
An error occurred (Throttling) when calling the ListStacks operation (reached max retries: 4): Rate exceeded
```

In particular if I happen to have the CloudFormation console open in my browser this happens pretty reliably.

I would like to configure it to be more forgiving in these cases -- either to back off more aggressively, or to retry more times. I've tried to find a way of doing this and have seen a few references to being able to do it in `boto`, but I can't see how to do it via the CLI.

Comment: Why are you calling `ListStacks` so multiple times?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I don't believe that I am calling it an unreasonable number of times. I've improved the text of the question to give more detail.

Comment: Ah! Okay, you're not calling it in parallel, just in sequence. Why are you calling it several times in a row in a (presumably) short space of time? What information are you seeking that you did not receive in a previous call? Are you waiting for a status to change? Are you calling `list-stacks` on a particular stack, or to retrieve details of all stacks? Are you using a `stack-status-filter`, or perhaps are you paging through a long list of stacks, which gives rise the need for repeated calls? Perhaps you show us some code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The other answers are good, but to answer the precise question: yes, define environment variable `AWS_MAX_ATTEMPTS`

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html

Comment: I'm pretty sure this didn't exist when I wrote the question, but it's the right answer now, so I'll accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Seems you're using `ListStack` for cloudformation service maybe implementing a polling and retry, a simpler solution is now built into the CLI for this: `aws <service> wait <condition>` so the polling is already implemented.

```
$ aws cloudformation wait stack-exists --stack-name <name of the stack>
```

Comment: I'm not doing the polling and retry myself, I'm just making a single call and the AWS CLI is retrying itself. I'd like to tweak the configuration of that retry.

Comment: ok, [S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/s3-config.html#configuration-values) has some config settings to be tweaked but I dont think there's equivalent for cloud formation. what do you really want to achieve ? as I believe the `wait` method should work in cases like this

Comment: I am checking to see whether a stack exists, so that I can extract outputs from it if it does. I am _not_ polling, just making three of these checks in quick succession. Unless I've missed something, I don't think that `wait` will help me here.

Comment: `wait` will help if you're creating the stack so it will appear when ready - I am clear though why you'll need to make 3 checks .. the 1st call should return the value; if you're not doing anything in parallel, nothing will change

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating some resources and waiting for that one to create successfully, AWS cli provided wait module[1] 
Since you want to retry for an error you can do a retry using while or until. Below code will run until command is successful.

```
while [ $? -ne 0 ]; do
YOUR COMMAND
GOOD CONDITION TO EXIT AFTER SOME RETRIES 
done
```

Make sure that you are using a good condition to exit after some retries otherwise it will end up with a infinite loop.

[1] http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/wait/index.html

Comment: Thank you, the wait operation looks very useful. However it's not applicable in my case because I am not waiting for something. I am calling `list-stacks` to see if a particular stack exists. I do this three or four times in a row, which seems to be enough to trigger the throttling.